# Weird SQL Group By query?

Tags: sql, group-by, duplicates

Sorry for the strange question title but not sure how to really describe this in a condensed way.

A client of ours would like me to write a query that eliminates duplicate records from their database. If we have a sample set of data like this:

```
╔══════╦════════╦════════╦═══════════════╗
║ Code ║ Amount ║ Client ║     Type      ║
╠══════╬════════╬════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 'a'  ║    950 ║ 'Lisa' ║ 'Available'   ║
║ 'b'  ║    550 ║ 'Bob'  ║ 'Unavailable' ║
║ 'b'  ║    500 ║ 'Bob'  ║ 'Available'   ║
║ 'c'  ║    500 ║ 'Dave' ║ 'Available'   ║
║ 'c'  ║    500 ║ 'Dave' ║ 'Unavailable' ║
╚══════╩════════╩════════╩═══════════════╝
```

They do not have a unique identifier for each record (unfortunately). A 'code' is referring to one entity, however it may have multiple records. So for example, I would like `SELECT Code, Amount, Client, Type`, `GROUP BY` 'Code', and select the record that has the `MIN(Amount)`.

I am able to pull the Code and Min(Amount) using GROUP BY, but I am having trouble selecting ALL of the columns for those particular records.

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what RDBMS you are using you might get what you want with the row_number function:

```
select code, amount, client, type
from (select *, row_number() over (partition by code order by amount) as rowrank 
      from table
     ) sub
where rowrank = 1
```

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server - this is exactly what I needed thank you so much!